# Google Ads in Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, ads

Can I use Google Ads in my Windows Store apps?

If yes, then How? Google AdSense requires me to enter a Web Site address for my content review. How can I tell them that I'm developing an App?

If No, then what Ad policy may I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently trying [Microsoft Pub Center](http://pubcenter.microsoft.com/) which is easy to setup in Windows Store Apps.

Answer (score 3):

Per [Google's page](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68724)

> The use of AdSense for mobile in a mobile application is a violation
>   of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable
>   application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad. Any AdSense
>   for mobile ad units found in mobile applications will be disabled. If
>   you’re looking for an advertising solution for your mobile
>   application, please sign up for [AdMob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/), Google’s leading mobile
>   advertising display product.

Comment: But what if your application is Mobile AND Windows 8 capable..? -Confused-

Comment: 'A mobile application constitutes any downloadable application'